# Swashbuckle HealthCheck Endpoint Exposing Exception Details After Switching from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, swagger, swashbuckle, system.text.json

I recently switched my .NET 6 project from using `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`. After making this change, I've encountered an unexpected behavior with one of my health check endpoints that utilizes `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheck`.

Before the switch, the Exception object in the Swagger UI response schema for this endpoint was not exposing any details, as desired. Now, after removing `AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport` and making the switch, the same endpoint's Exception object is exposing internal properties (see image below with System.Text.Json).

Current Swagger UI with System.Text.Json:

[image]

For comparison, here is the Swagger UI with Newtonsoft.Json where the exception object was empty:

[image]

I have not made any other changes to the configuration of Swashbuckle or the health check endpoint. It seems like the default behavior for handling exceptions has changed with System.Text.Json.

I'm looking for a way to configure Swashbuckle or System.Text.Json to prevent these internal details from being exposed in the Swagger UI. Any suggestions on how to revert to the previous behavior where the Exception class does not expose its properties would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the `HealthReport` and associated types were ever intended to be explicitly used as the DTOs to return from a service, because they lack explicit attributes to control how they are (de)serialized. I would suggest that you either make your own models to do the data transfer where you can control the serialization, or suppress the endpoints from the OpenAPI schema entirely. Another option would be to use a custom `ISchemaFilter` implementation and manually remove what you want from the schema before it is returned to the user.

Comment: ^ What Martin said - the fact that your endpoint _wasn't_ exposing these properties with Newtonsoft is a very lucky coincidence. If you had updated to a newer version of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` which added or removed properties from the `HealthCheck` object, you would've seen similar unexpected behaviour. You almost never should return third-party objects, which can change unexpectedly over time, from your own services.

Comment: Thanks, Martin and Ian! I completely forgot about that. I'll map the responses to my custom DTOs, ensuring better control. We have custom DTO's for healthcheck but i did not think about it.

Your insights are much appreciated!

Comment: API contracts are generally for consumers who want to call the API - and who will threfore not be calling the healthcheck endpoint. It's questionable whether you even should include it in the API contract.